# Как правильно написать такой jQuery скрипт?

Tags: jquery

Мне нужно написать такой jQuery скрипт:

Когда посетитель прокручивает страницу [сайта](http://dental1.brandivo.com/) вниз, в шапке исчезает все, кроме главного меню, а когда прокручивает в самый верх, шапка опять полностью появляется.

Вот что есть на данный момент:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        jQuery("#header").not('#header_main_alternate').hide('slow');
    })
})
```

Почему-то, несмотря на `.not('#header_main_alternate')`, прячется вся шапка. Помогите, пожалуйста, дописать скрипт!

Comment: @eprivalov1, а чему ж вы удивляетесь, если '*#header_main_alternate*' - это дочерний элемент. Или раметку меняйте, или уже делать так:

    jQuery("#header *").not('#header_main_alternate').hide('slow');

Comment: @Deonis спасибо за совет, но так тоже исчезает и Главное Меню

Comment: @eprivalov1, так этот элемент еще и не прямой потомок... В общем, поизвращаться можно, но аплодировать будут только индусы:

    jQuery("#header > * ").not('#header_main').hide('slow');
    jQuery("#header_main > * ").not('#header_main_alternate').hide('slow');

Лучше задуматься об изменении структуры или же клонировать меню, скрывать все элементы шапки и выводить клона.

Comment: @Deonis а если не извращаться с .not(), а просто перечислить нужные классы и id и спрятать их?!

Comment: @eprivalov1, можно и так.

Comment: @Deonis первую часть скрипта я написал, а как мне описать ту часть, где посетитель начинает прокрутку вверх и шапка обратно появляется, поможете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот посмотри http://pcvector.net/scripts/layout_and_interface/390-lipkiy-header.html

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что у меня получилось:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var headerHeight = $("#header").height();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>= headerHeight) { 
            // header just passed
            $(".logo, .social_bookmarks, .phone-info, #header_main>.container, #header_meta").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        else{
            $(".logo, .social_bookmarks, .phone-info, #header_main>.container, #header_meta").fadeIn('fast');
        }
    })
})
```